# Can't boot my server after fstab optimizations

Tags: fstab

After optimizng the fstab values for my main server HDD, the server is unable to boot and i can't debug it because i'm controlling it remotly, this what i've entered

```
/dev/sda1       /               ext3    defaults,usrquota,noatime,nodiratime,data=writeback,commit=30 1 1
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0 0
sysfs           /sys            sysfs   defaults        0 0
/dev/sda2       swap            swap    defaults        0 0
none            /dev/pts        devpts  rw              0 0
none            /var/tmp        tmpfs   defaults,rw,noexec,nosuid,noatime,nodiratime,size=3g 0 0
tmpfs           /dev/shm        tmpfs   defaults            0 0
```

What is wrong with those values? i'm using centos 64bit

Comment: Does your server have enough RAM to support a 3 gigabyte `tmpfs` RAM disk?

Comment: I have 8G.B RAM, what you think?

Comment: Be more specific about "unable to boot."

Answer (score 2):

Are these two separate lines in your fstab?

"none /var/tmp tmpfs

defaults,rw,noexec,nosuid,noatime,nodiratime,size=3g 0 0"

If so, that is a problem.

Even if they are a single line, I think it is still a problem. Except for "size=3g", none of those options you specified are valid mount options for a tmpfs. You can view the valid options in the manpage for mount.

Comment: They are single line but i saw those values used already on a box, how they managed to boot with those values?